# Создание связей между сущностями при создании заказа пользователя

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Что в описанной жиже ситуации я делаю неправильно?

Создаю заказ покупателя:

```
$co = (new CustomerOrder($this->moysklad, [
                "name" => "shop_".$data['order_id']
            ]))
            ->buildCreation()
            ->addCounterparty($cp)
            ->addOrganization($org)
            ->addPositionList($positionList)
            ->execute();
```

Создаю входящий платеж, передавая в него созданный заказ:

```
$paymentIn = (new PaymentIn($this->moysklad, []))
                ->buildCreation()
                ->addCounterparty($cp)
                ->addOrganization($org)
                ->addCustomerOrder($co)
                ->execute();
```

а именно через метод addCustomerOrder($co).
В МойСклад создаются все необходимые сущности (контрагент, заказ и входящий платеж), но по факту между платежом и заказом нет никакой связи. Кроме того во входящем платеже нет информации о сумме заказа.

Comment: https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F по доке есть связи с платежами. Возможно json, который вы формируете для отправления через апи, не содержит в себе  ссылок (см секцию СВЯЗИ С ДРУГИМИ ДОКУМЕНТАМИ)

Comment: Связи то есть, только как их связать не очевидно, как все другое по этому api, поэтому и пытаюсь найти рабочий пример

Comment: В заголовке вопроса не нужно указывать "решено", просто отмечайте ответ принятым или добавляйте свой ответ (ответ должен быть в ответе, а не в самом вопросе, даже если вы сами нашли его).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для платежей связи определяются в массиве operations. Указывается мета связанного документа и сумма, оплаченная из этого платежа.

```
"operations": [  
  {  
    "meta":{  
      "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/019fc442-c0dc-11e8-9107-5048002aed15",
      "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/metadata",
      "type":"customerorder",
      "mediaType":"application/json",
      "uuidHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#customerorder/edit?id=019fc442-c0dc-11e8-9107-5048002aed15"
    },
    "linkedSum":10000
  }
]
```

Comment: ок, если через командную строку делать запрос, то все работает. Только живые примеры все равно остаются актуальны